# C# Regex matching JSON api response correctly

Tags: c#, json, regex

I am trying to match Blockchain JSON Api response right way, but it seems like I just can't do it. Blockchain API Response looks like that:

```
{
    "addresses": [
        {
            "balance": 1400938800,
            "address": "1Q1AtvCyKhtveGm3187mgNRh5YcukUWjQC",
            "label": "SMS Deposits",
            "total_received": 5954572400
        },
        {
            "balance": 79434360,
            "address": "1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq",
            "label": "My Wallet",
            "total_received": 453300048335
        },
        {
            "balance": 0,
            "address": "17p49XUC2fw4Fn53WjZqYAm4APKqhNPEkY",
            "total_received": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically, like you can see. For each address is each line, on C# ReadToEnd(), gives me it messed up. But basically I am trying that, if there is label SMS Deposits example, then from "that line" it will take that Address, no where else. Example: label is Peter, then it takes address only from Peter line, not any other line. How could I do that? Here is also my code:

```
    listAddresses.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse listAddressesResp = (HttpWebResponse)listAddresses.GetResponse();
    StreamReader listAddressesSR = new StreamReader(listAddressesResp.GetResponseStream());
    var resultListAddresses = listAddressesSR.ReadToEnd();
    if (resultListAddresses.Contains(name))
    {
        Regex SuiWillThatWork = new Regex("\"address\":\"[A-Za-z0-9]+");
        var TestingVol2 = SuiWillThatWork.Match(resultListAddresses).Value;
        TestingVol2 = TestingVol2.Replace("\"address\":\"", "");
        address = TestingVol2;
        MessageBox.Show(resultListAddresses);
        MessageBox.Show(address);
    }
```

Comment: XY Problem? Instead of hacking this to work, go get [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) and treat JSON as it should be treated.

Comment: Yeah, alright. If I "treat" it right way, then still.. How I could regex that information from that "line/block"

Comment: If you treat it like JSON, there's absolutely no reason to continue using RegEx. And even if you did get it working with regex, 1) it would be fragile and probably won't work in every circumstance, 2) Fragile is especially true should the vendor change the API/response, 3) there's already a parser--use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex for something that already has a really nice parser developed. Go do yourself a favor and `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json` and try something like the following:

First, establish objects that match the response coming back. If you're lazy, there are tools available (such as [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/)) which make this very easy. For your response, how about something like the following:

```
class ServerResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("addresses")]
    public List<AddressResponse> Addresses { get; set; }
}
class AddressResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("balance")]
    public long Balance { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("total_received")]
    public long TotalReceived { get; set; }
}
```

*Note: You don't have to go the `JsonPropertyAttribute` way, but I like to make my models follow naming conventions.*

Next, we need to deserialize the response into our new object. Using Newtonsoft, it's as easy as:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(jsonResponse);
```

You now have a fully hydrated object:

```
ServerResponse
  Addresses (List<AddressResponse> (3 items))
    Balance     Address                            Label         TotalReceived
    1400938800  1Q1AtvCyKhtveGm3187mgNRh5YcukUWjQC SMS Deposits  5954572400 
    79434360    1A8JiWcwvpY7tAopUkSnGuEYHmzGYfZPiq My Wallet     453300048335 
    0           17p49XUC2fw4Fn53WjZqYAm4APKqhNPEkY null          0
```

---

To get back to the problem at hand, now we can look for "SMS Deposits" and retrieve the address:

```
var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(jsonResponse);
var smsDeposits = response.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Label == "SMS Deposits");
if (smsDeposits != null)
{
   MessageBox.Show(smsDeposits.Address);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time and helping me out!